# i am trying to use a variable created in the main function in an if statement but it says that it is an unknown identifier

Tags: c++

I am making a car rental service and am trying to write to an already existing file.
I made a previous file that has the username they entered as the name of the file. This is where the problem comes in, I made an if statement and used ofstream file and then did file.open(username + ".txt") but when I do this vs code says the identifier is unknown. The variable was made in the main function and the if statement is in the main function and I am unsure how to proceed. here is ever line of code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


bool IsLoggedIn(){
std::string username, password, un, pw;
std::cout << "enter your username: "; std::cin >> username;
std::cout << "enter your password: "; std::cin >> password;
//checks the file for a password and username 
std::ifstream read(username + ".txt");
getline(read, un);
getline(read, pw);
if(un == username && pw == password){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

};

int main(){
    int choice;
    std::string option;
std::cout << "hello welcome to nathans car rental press 1 to register press 2 to login: "; std::cin >> choice;
if(choice == 1){
    std::string username, password;
    std::cout << "make a username: "; std::cin >> username;
    std::cout << "make a password: "; std::cin >> password;
    //makes a file and puts the username and password in it 
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(username + ".txt");
    file << username << std::endl << password;
    file.close();
    main();
} else if (choice == 2){
    bool status = IsLoggedIn();
    if(!status){
        std::cout << "you do not have an account" << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }else{
        std::cout << "welcome back" << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
std::cout << "what car would you like to rent maserati=m lamborghini=l and ferrari=f" << std::endl;
std::cin >> option;
if(option == "m"){
    std::cout << "you now have the maserati" << std::endl;
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(username + ".txt");
}
};
```

the red squiggly line is at the username in the bottom in file.open()

Comment: fyi: it is forbidden to call `main()`

Comment: username is defined within the `if` scope. you need to declare it outside the `if` if you want to use it later.

Comment: it is not forbidden to call `main()` but you have to be sure you exit it as many times as you enter, or your stack will overflow, it is often used in C/C++ obfuscated contest programs or if you try to minimize the text code size, `main()` is just like any other function in C/C++, it is called by the C/C++ library after the startup initialization

Comment: @rioV8 Obfuscated C Contest programs sometimes teach unrecommended programming styles. main shall not be used/called from within the program: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3

Comment: @Sebastian I don't promote the use of calling `main()` I just correct the statement by Raildex that it is forbidden. The compiler accepts. It is not good practice in general programs, but I have seen some creative uses for the fun programming code.

Comment: @rioV8 It may work with a lot of compilers and C/C++ runtimes, but it is not allowed for strictly standard compliant well-formed programs to do so. Which does mean you can or should do forbidden things for educational and fun purposes at home. Technically Raildex is right.

Comment: @rioV8 That the compiler accepts a program does not imply that it is valid.  [basic.start.main] of C++17 says "The function `main` shall not be used within a program." Perhaps you're thinking about C, where it *is* allowed.

Comment: @molbdnilo It says `shall not be used` that means it `can be used`, it is not forbidden, it is bad practice, `shall not` does not imply `can not`, `can not` implies `shall not`

Comment: @molbdnilo If I write a program and the compiler generates an executable it is a valid program, and if that does what I want it is also a useful program.

Comment: @rioV8 `shall` is standardese for `forbidden`, if you want to conform to the standard. Those qualifiers do not have everyday meaning.

Comment: @rioV8 The standard says it is undefined behaviour to call `main()`. So it is effectively forbidden to call it if you want a well-formed program that you can talk about. The reason is that some compilers add extra startup/shutdown stuff to main (not all of them but some).

Comment: @rioV8 • I'm aware of the International Obfuscated C Code Contest.  What obfuscated C++ contests are there?  (And... why would we want them?  Makes no sense, just as it makes no sense to have an obfuscated Perl contest.)

Answer (score 2):

you have to define your variables outside the if, if you want to use them